# Prevent changes from being saved to sqlite database in a hosted demo project?

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, web-applications, web-hosting

I have a demo app designed in php/laravel with a sqlite database & dummy data that I want to add to my portfolio, for users to test. I want users to be able to interact with the app and make changes, however i do not want them to be committed to the database file.

Anyone know what the best way to achieve this would be?
I have seen a few projects on themeforest/codecanyon implement something similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make changes to the database and show them to the users, without those changes being persisted in the database. So if you want the users to be able test out functionality that involves storing/updating/deleting entries in the database, your best bet is to reset the database periodically (like once an hour).

You can use [Task Scheduling](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) to either run some [seeding classes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding) or whatever way you like to empty and repopulate the database with the original dummy data. This is a simple example of what you can add to the `schedule` method in your `app/Console/Kernel.php` file to run database seeding every hour:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Artisan::call('db:seed');
    })->hourly();
}
```